# Can't Access Static IP from VM on Different Network

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtual-machine, parallels, static-ip

I am running Parallels 10 on my MacBook Pro (Mav 10.9.4). The guest VM is windows 7. The network is set to be Bridged.

I have installed a web server on the Windows Guest. I am using a static IP 10.10.10.10 created on a Windows 7 loopback adapter to host this web server. On my hosts file in windows, I have provided the WinVMName for this IP (10.10.10.10). I am able to access the webpage from Safari on my Mac Host hooked onto my home network, using the link `http://WinVMName:7001/`. But the moment I move out to some other network, the webpage is no longer accessible. What could be going wrong?

Comment: I’m not that familiar with Parallels. What kind of network config are you using? Bridged, NAT or host-only...?

Comment: It's a Bridged network, Daniel - Sorry, I should have mentioned that. Please give me some directions on how you would set it up on any Virtualization Software. I would try and see if I can simulate this on Parallels.

Comment: Is the Windows VM getting a valid IP address when you move to a different network?  If not you may want to change it to Shared networking.

Comment: Yes it does get a valid IP. I should be in a position to access my webpage as 'http://WinVMName:7001/' from safari on Mac. And this WinVMName is set to 10.10.10.10 within hosts file on Windows. Can "Shared Networking" help me achieve this?

Comment: If you want to access your VM without relying on the state of other networks, I recommend using a host-only network. I bet Parallels offers this option too.